# Hazelcast - executeOnEntries to stop after the first execution

Tags: java, caching, hazelcast

I have a question regarding Hazelcast processors. 
Is there a way to make an EntryProcessor stops its execution after the first one?

Let's say I have to remove the entry that has a key matching a certain condition.
key A12 value 123
key 1234 value 345
I want to remove the first entry that has '1' in its key. (A12)
How do I remove it without iterating the entry set, by using a filter and an entry processor ( remove only the first matched entry, skip the following one. use executeOnEntries(processor, predicate). I know that I can iterate myself over the entry set of the map and remove it, but I would like to know if there is another solution.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you cannot do this with an EntryProcessor, however we're working on a stream processing engine which is about to be released shortly (as early access). Current plan for release is close to Hazelcast 3.8 release which is in January. If you're interested let us know. We have a private beta program but not sure if there's still an available seat but I can make contact with right person :)

Comment: Thanks for the response! I will wait for the release of the new version!